# Big query will impact performance

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am having a big query by joining some 8 tables and i will get all the details using that single query itself.

Now i want to know whether it is good to join all the tables together or we can run separate query to get the details inside the loop using the id from the main query? And, Is it good to run queries inside loop?

Below is the query which i am using,

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid,
       node.uid,
   node.title AS node_title, 
   og.og_description AS og_og_description,
   node.created AS node_created,  
   og.og_selective AS og_og_selective, 
tn.tid, 
td.name as groupcategory,
(select count(ou.uid) from og_uid ou,users u where ou.uid=u.uid and u.status=1 and ou.is_active=1 and ou.nid=node.nid) as ucount,
f.filepath,
CONCAT(statusbook_users.first_name,' ',statusbook_users.last_name) AS users_name
FROM node node 
LEFT JOIN og og ON node.nid = og.nid 
INNER JOIN content_type_group ctg ON (node.nid = ctg.nid AND ctg.field_cn_group_type_value IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN files f ON (ctg.field_group_image_fid = f.fid)
INNER JOIN users users ON node.uid = users.uid
INNER JOIN statusbook_users statusbook_users ON users.uid= statusbook_users.uid
INNER JOIN og_uid og_uid ON og.nid=og_uid.nid 
INNER JOIN term_node tn ON node.nid=tn.nid 
INNER JOIN term_data td ON tn.tid=td.tid 
WHERE (node.status <> 0) AND (node.type IN ('group'))
AND og_uid.is_active=1 AND og_uid.uid=65
```

And the time execution for the above query in my localsystem is 12824.59 ms and when i ran the same query in production server, it took 217.34 ms

Is there any way to optimize the above query still??

Comment: Benchmark it and see -- generally a single query will run faster than multiple queries (especially in while loops).  Hitting the database is expensive.  With that said, it depends -- benchmark and see.

Comment: If your indexes are set and fit the query, just let MySQL play

Comment: @ringo - Yeah i have added indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually better to make one large query and let the DBMS optimizer do the hard work of figuring out the fastest way to complete your query. It is usually much better at this than you are.

However to know for sure, you should try both versions and profile.